# 1 to 1 required relationship with database generated identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have seen many examples of implementing a one to one relationship, but I failed doing mine, because the requirements are some kind different (Guid with database generated option, foreign key property and so on).

I have 2 classes (Bundesland, Programmkonfiguration) that have a 1:1 relationship (both ends are required in business sense) but cannot be joined into one table

Requirements to Bundesland:

- Guid Id as Key but without a DatabaseGenerated Attribute
- Navigation Property Programmkonfiguration

Bundesland.cs:

```
public class Bundesland
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Programmkonfiguration Programmkonfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

Requirements to Bundesland

- Guid Id as Key generated from Database
- ForeignKey Property Bundesland_Id (needed with _ for interface)
- Navigation Property Bundesland

Programmkonfiguration.cs:

```
public class Programmkonfiguration
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Bundesland_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Bundesland Bundesland { get; set; }
}
```

database schema should look like this

- table Bundesland (Id)
- table Programmkonfiguration (Id, Bundesland_Id)

Why I failed until now:

- EF doesn’t recognize the relationship by itself
- if I use either attributes (ForeignKey, Required) or fluent API and the mode builder is not failing, the foreign key property Programmkonfiguration.Bundesland_Id is never set, after context.SaveChanges()

If you want to help me, here are additional classes you may gonna need: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9cb554cd864e3dbee1ac

I am using .NET 4.5(.1) with EF5, but I failed with EF6 too

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent configuration for this:

```
public class Bundesland
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Programmkonfiguration")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Programmkonfiguration Programmkonfiguration { get; set; }
}

public class BundesLandConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Bundesland>
{
    public BundesLandConfiguration()
    {            
        HasProperty(p=>p.Id)
        HasRequired(p=>p.Programmkonfiguration).WithRequiredPrincipal(p=>p.Bundesland);
    }
}

public class Programmkonfiguration
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Bundesland_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Bundesland Bundesland { get; set; }
}

public class ProgrammkonfigurationConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Programmkonfiguration>
{
    public ProgrammkonfigurationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p=>p.Id);
        HasProperty(p=>p.Id)
        HasProperty(p=>p.Bundesland_Id)
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add this configurations to EntityModelConfigurations in db context.

**Update:** because property naming is against convention, you should add [ForeignKey] attribute as I added to property Id of Bundesland class.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it neither works (Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'OneToOneRelation.Model.Programmkonfiguration' and 'OneToOneRelation.Model.Bundesland'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.) nor does it meet my requirements (Programmkonfiguration.Bundesland_Id)

I tried already a dozens of different configurations and couldn't find the right one, so everything works like expected.

Comment: I updated my answer. Because property naming is against convention, you should add [ForeignKey] attribute as I added to property Id of Bundesland class.

Comment: And you should add configuration classes to your dbcontext. Have you done this?

Comment: When using your example the exception _A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'._ is thrown.

**I do** understand the concept of mapping relationships using entity framework. It just seems to be an uncommon situation with my requirements.

I tried various approaches (ForeignKey, fluent API vs. attributes, and so on), so I am looking for a working solution fulfilling the requirements from my first post.